# in depth understating of Object detection data augmentation

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection, object-detection-api

I am trying to use the data augmentation features of the object detection API. I have configured the augmentation option in the config file. I am using below git hub repository for it. 
https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/object_detection

I have used below configuration in config file.

```
data_augmentation_options {
      random_pixel_value_scale {
      minval: 0.6
    }
}
```

in **trainer.py** file below method is getting called for augmentation.

```
tensor_dict = preprocessor.preprocess(
           tensor_dict, data_augmentation_options,
          func_arg_map=preprocessor.get_default_func_arg_map(
                include_instance_masks=include_instance_masks,
              include_keypoints=include_keypoints))
```

**My question is number of images are getting increased after the preprocessing. If yes how to validate tha**t ? tensor_dict length is 12 before and after the preprocessing.

Answer (score 1):

The number of images per step that your model is going to see is defined in the config file by the parameter `batch_size`

```
train_config: {
  batch_size: N
  . . .
```

**None** of the `data_augmentation` options will incriease/decrease the images per step (tensor_dict) your network is receiving. The `data_augmentation` options will just randomly alter the original batch.

One could interpret that the `data_augmentation` options are kind of augmenting the effective size of your dataset because for the same image, the network would receive each time a slighly different version of the image. (depending on the actual `data_augmentation` parameters you are using).